# DRY in CoffeeScript Function

Tags: coffeescript, dry

Working on an exercise from "CoffeeScript - Accelerated JavaScript Development," I'm trying to write this function without duplication:

```
doAndRepeatUntil = (f, pred) ->
  f() 
  f() until pred()
```

How can I write this function without calling `f()` twice?

Comment: If you check under Appendix 1.2, you'll find you already have the answer the exercise was asking for. The goal was just to contain the repetition within a function, not to eradicate it completely. Are you intentionally trying for the extra step?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the way you wrote it is the preferred one. To avoid two calls to `f` one could write:

```
doAndRepeatUntil = (f, pred) ->
  loop
    f()
    break if pred()
```

But I would argue that it is less readable and elegant (equivalent to using `while (true)`).